# Was there ever an Options Dialog Wizard in Visual Studio .Net..?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, vb6

Was there ever an "Options" dialog wizard in Visual Studio .Net? If so, does anyone remember what it was called and where it can be found?

I seem to recall such a thing in some version of Visual Studio. It created the dialog and hooked up the control values to the `Settings` section of `Project Properties`. But I cannot remember which version, or how it was accessed.

I thought it was Visual Studio .Net, but it's possible it was VB6.

Comment: In VB6 it's one of the dialogs available in the Project > Add Form dialog, but it only sets up a skeleton form with four tabs and the code for hiding and showing the frame associated with each tab plus 'Ok', 'Cancel' and 'Apply' buttons. No idea about VB.Net.

Comment: That might be what I'm thinking of. Now that I'm thinking of VB6, I think the Options wizard was part of a larger Application Wizard.

Comment: @spinjector Yes, there is also a `VB Application Wizard` available when you create a new project.